# Change android:windowBackground in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement Splash Screen using Jetpack Compose. In the old View system, we can just change the `android:windowBackground` via XML Theme.

How to do this in Compose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I looked into the `AndroidManifest.xml`, I saw that the app is still using old `themes.xml` for its activities.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppName">
```

From here I just edit the theme to apply a `windowBackground`

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

I did not create a new style and just use the main style. It's enough to just apply a white `Surface` on the root composable to hide the splash background when the activity showed up.

Comment: I was dying to find a way to hide the initial flicker of the white screen while loading the app, which everyone said was not possible to avoid. I've set my primary color as the window background as you said, and the white screen flicker is now gone! Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 2):

The Window Background is something specific to Android itself, it tells the system what background this activity draws "At All times".

For example, an activity with no view at all can still have a background, as it is defined in its theme. This is actually used for stuff like Splash Screens, as they have no UI, just a background. Since the background of an activity takes no time to draw, while the UI can get delayed.

Compose is a UI framework, and any UI will only be drawn when it's ready, meaning it will only show when the activity is ready. So a splash screen is impossible in Compose. More like, it's unrelated.

If you just want to set a background to your entire UI, maybe put the entire UI in a `Box` with a background. Or set the background colour in the `MaterialTheme`. And if you're not using a theme, just make a common Composable that's just a `Box`

Comment: As I have specified, I want to implement a Splash Screen. And in this case, using composable won't work since it takes time to render (it is called after MainActivity `onCreate`), while the app only shows a blank white screen.

Comment: As I said, windowBackground is an Android thing. Meaning, Splash Screens is an Android thing. You can't make a Splash Screen in Compose, as Compose is a UI framework, and UI takes a while to draw